# Android toast different activity/fragment

Tags: android, toast

I am using toast on android, However I dont want the toast to disappear. but rather stay...
And I dont want the toast to show up on different activity or fragment.
If I called toast in certain fragment, i dont want it to be seen in a different fragment or activity.
Lets say activity 1, i call toast..i go to activity 2... i dont want toast to be displayed yet. when i return to activity 1 i see the toast still in place.
I also want this for fragments.

> Toast toast = Toast.makeText(dialog.getContext(),R.string.serverError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>                                                           toast.show();

Comment: Make a class and extend the Toast class, define the methods to show and cancel the toast, now use this custom toast class in your activity, and show the toast when you want and, cancel it over onPause() or onStop() or onDestroy(), in which method, you have to decide. Don't go with Handlers, postdelayed or runnables, it just make your code heavy and un-managable. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to make the Toast `global` in your Fragment/Activity. Now you can call [Toast.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29) in a callback like `onPause()`, which is called if you switch an Activity or Fragment.

The docs say about cancel:

> Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing
>   yet. ...

A nicer way is to make a custom class for the Toast like jitain sharma suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that Toast should not remain on the screen when you move out of Activity then I would suggest you to use third party library [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

in `Fragment:`

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       toast.cancel(); 
                   }
            }, 500);
```

in `Activity:`

```
 final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       toast.cancel(); 
                   }
            }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your activity `onDestory` method:

```
toast.cancel();
```